# select2 - expandable hierarchical levels?

Tags: jquery-select2

select2 is able to display hierarchical JSON data, but for a large taxonomy (~3000 elements & 9 levels of depth) it would be ideal to have expandable levels, so by default it only shows 'level_1' elements instead of all ~3000 elements, where it could expand to further levels by clicking on a '+' sign and contract by clicking on a '-' sign.

- Is this currently possible?
- If not, can anybody suggest what would be the best approach to extend select2 to achieve this functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible, but [there's an open ticket for this for Select2](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3269).